# One of the symbols of the font used look odd, what are my options to fix it?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I have enjoyed the `mathptmx` package font for some time. However recently I discovered that `mathptmx` used the really wide double integral symbol (`iint`) which looks much like this:

[image: doubleintegral symbol used by mathptmx]

I would much rather use the traditional sleeker symbol for the integral:

[image: Convensional symbol]

Can I fix this somehow? Either substitute the symbol for another one, or do something else?

Comment: You can use another font with a integral symbol design sleeker you want. It's better instead to try to deform the symbol above. I prefer `mathpazo` or `euler-vm`.

Comment: As also noted by @Dan in his answer, the double integral symbol produced by the `mathptmx` package does not look anything like the one that's featured in your screenshot. Please consider posting an MWE that produces the heavy double integral.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't mean the `newtxmath` package?

I get the second sleeker form (the Computer Modern integrals) when using only `mathptmx`. I get the first wider form when I use only the `newtxmath` package.

I think that the `newtx` packages have more flexibility on this score, because you can arrange for either integral sign to be used. The following gives the thicker wider integrals you don't want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Test
\[ \iint \]
\end{document}
```

The following gives the sleeker CM integrals you seek:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Test
\[ \iint \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The double integral produced by `newtxmath` and its precursor, `txfonts` -- while certainly heavier than that produced by `mathptmx` -- actually don't look nearly as heavy as the one featured in the OP's screenshot.

Comment: @Mico My main point was that on my system, `mathptmx` actually produces the `CM` integrals, which look nothing like either the screenshot nor what is provided by `newtxmath`. However, there is some resemblance between `txfonts`/`newtx` integrals and that screenshot. I kind of assumed the screenshot was an approximation, since Marius wrote "looks much like this".